# java sockets address already in use exception

Tags: java, sockets

I'm facing a strange problem doing java sockets project. Here's my code:
Server:

```
package second.sockets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Server implements Runnable {

    public static String HOST = "localhost";
    public static int PORT = 1234;

    private static final int MAX_USERS = 2;
    private static final Server serverInstance = new Server();
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    private Server() {
        try {
            if( this.serverSocket == null ) {
                this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Server.PORT);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("could not initialize ServerSocket on port="+Server.PORT +
                    "["+ e.getMessage() +"]");
        }
    }

    public static Server getInstance() {
        return Server.serverInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("waiting for incoming connections...");
        try {
            while( !Thread.interrupted() ) {
                this.waitForFreeSlots();
                Socket newSocket=null;
                try {
                    newSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("new connection " + newSocket);
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("could not connect");
                }
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("server interrupted");
        }
    }

    private synchronized void waitForFreeSlots() throws InterruptedException {
        while( this.users.size() >= Server.MAX_USERS ) {
            this.wait();
        }
    }

    public static int getPORT() {
        return PORT;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Server server = Server.getInstance();
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(server);
        serverThread.start();

    }
}
```

Client:

```
package second.sockets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket=null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(Server.HOST, Server.PORT);
        } catch(UnknownHostException uhe) {
            System.err.println("could not connect to "+Server.HOST+" on port "+Server.PORT+", no such host");
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("could not connect to "+Server.HOST + " on port "+Server.PORT);
        }
        System.out.println(socket);
    }

}
```

I run the server and it works, but when I run a Client I get `could not initialize ServerSocket on port=1234[Address already in use: JVM_Bind]` and it is from Server code from line 25. It's odd as Server is a singleton so there's no place for more than one instance of the class. What is more I don't even touch it in Client `main` function. I don't get it, any ideas where the problem is? Thanks.

EDIT:
Here's the stack trace. It comes from Server's constructor although it is private and it shows after running the Client.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at second.sockets.Server.<init>(Server.java:22)
    at second.sockets.Server.<clinit>(Server.java:15)
    at second.sockets.Client.main(Client.java:12)
    could not initialize ServerSocket on port=21234[Address already in use: JVM_Bind]
    Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=21234,localport=53054]
```

I don't get this transition:
`at second.sockets.Client.main(Client.java:12)`->`at second.sockets.Server.<clinit>(Server.java:15)`

Comment: Is anything else running on 1234?

Comment: the port does not seem to matter as I tried it with some random values for `Server.PORT`. The behaviour is the same every time.

Comment: Were those "random values" below 1024?  Those ports would require special permission to use.  Try a number that's kind of out there, like 21234;  the likelihood of any app using that is slim.

Comment: I tried some of the big values. I don't think this is the problem. It seems to be the internal application issue. Those instances bother me. It's like client coliding with server instead of cooperating.

Comment: IF you are suing eclipse, go to window-> show view-Debug you will find an instance of your Server already running, terminate it and you should be fine, you wont get that exception (except that `User` class isn't defined anywhere).

Comment: `netstat -ano | find "1234"` will return the PID number of the process using port 1234. You could then check task manager or `taskkill /F /PID:<PID>` to terminate the process.

Comment: question updated with stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stuff you see in the exception comes from the fact that you are using Server.HOST and Server.PORT in your client code. This calls the class initializer for the Server class. In this initializer all the static stuff in the Server class is created. And I see you have a static Server instance there...so you have in fact several Server instances created.

So avoid using Server.HOST and Server.PORT in the client code and use the real valus directly and it will work.

Normally when you want to share stuff between 2 code entities, move them to a third entity to decouple the server and client. Then let server and client use that new entity.

Comment: Basically I went wrong in singleton approach. It should has the initialization in the method `getInstance()` if the reference is `null`.

Comment: The thing is that the client code should not affect how the server code is structured. So you could still have a singleton approach (whether or not that is a good idea is a different matter) for the server. Just make sure that you have a third class, e.g ServerSettings that holds the constants HOST and PORT.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out what was wrong. In Client in this line `socket = new Socket(Server.HOST, Server.PORT);` I was using 2 variables from class `Server`. When I deleted it and pasted raw values or cahnge the variables to be `final`, it started to work. This is some wild magic.